# Should I test calls to my service inside BootstrapDialog prompt?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, bootstrap-dialog

I am using BootstrapDialog to show a dialog box. If the user clicks delete it calls my service and deletes it from the database. If they click cancel it closes the dialog.

I am writing unit tests and this one is puzzling me. The call to my service is nested pretty deep and I wouldn't even know how to make the tests know which path I'm testing.

My code in the controller:

```
$scope.deleteInventoryEntry = function(id){

    //launch dialog
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'CONFIRM DELETION',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
        closable: false,
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
        buttons: [{
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    action: function(dialog) {    
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                    action: function(dialog) {
                            //remove item from database                     
                            tankService.deleteInventoryEntry(id).success(function (response) {
                                //remove item from table if successful
                                if(response > 0){

                                    //figure out which item to remove from table
                                    var pos = $scope.invTable.filtered.map(function(item) { return item._id; }).indexOf(id);    
                                    //remove from table
                                    $scope.invTable.filtered.splice(pos,1);
                                    $scope.selectedItem.lineItems = [];
                                    dialog.close();

                                    //$scope.successGrowl('  QC Deleted Successfully');
                                }   

                            });

                        }
                    }
                ]       
    });
};
```

My Test

```
it('prompts on delete inventory item', function(){
       spyOn(BootstrapDialog, 'show').and.callThrough();
        $scope.deleteInventoryEntry(1);

        expect(BootstrapDialog.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I can also test if say the ID was NAN or Null and the dialog shouldn't show. But I'm just curious if I should be somehow testing tankService.deleteInventoryEntry() was called. I feel like I should but does that mean I have to mock this entire dialog item?

Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb to any testing. Don't test the implementation, but the behavior. For instance you should test that when you filled a form and clicked a submit button it was sent to your API and something happened in response. Tests should be independent from the view part as much as possible (eg. was the form located in a modal or somewhere in the page).